# send XML data to server from JS and get XML parameter

Tags: xml

In Javascript I can send XML string to JSP server (XmlAction.jsp):

Javascript Code:

```
var xmlDocument = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
                        <Customer>
                             .......
                         </Customer> 
                    "
 var httpRequest;

 httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();    
 httpRequest.open('POST', "http://example.com/XmlAction.jsp", false);
 httpRequest.send(xmlDocument);
```

My question: How can I get XML data in JSP Page XmlAction.jsp ?

Can you give me some java code.
Thank all ^^

Comment: I think you meant Javascript code not Java. Javascript contains the word "Java" only for marketing reasons. The two languages are totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [request.getInputStream()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29) to get a stream of the submitted XML body, and pass it to whatever XML parser you plan to use (eg. for DOM an implementation of [DocumentBuilder.parse(stream)](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29), which you might get from javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory).

Having a non-web-form (application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data) POST body is slightly unusual for Servlet/JSP but should work okay. Just make sure nothing is calling methods like getParameter() which expect web form input, and will get confused if you've already read the input stream.

[aside: do you really mean ISO-8859-1? If you send Unicode characters in a body with XMLHttpRequest.send(), they will be encoded as UTF-8, which won't match your XML declaration.]